# Left joining a KStream on another Kstream, but only with "latest" results

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a data stream on Kafka that I stream as a Kstream. Next to it I have a meta data stream that I would like to enrich the data stream with. A fairly common scenario present in several examples.

What I haven't solved is when the meta data stream contains more than one result for the specified window. What is commonly wanted in this scenario is to join it with the latest, or last, element from the meta data stream. A sales order would for example be materialised once, with the latest customer object, not twice for each sequential customer update.

Imagine the following scenario:

[image]

When element 7 (green) arrives it gets joined with 2 and 3 from the meta data stream, even though only 3 is relevant (in my case).

I realise this could be a good match for a Kstream<-Ktable join, where the Ktable only would contain the latest record in the meta data stream. But that has the huge disadvantage in that it will not cope with late and out-of-order data in a good fashion.

The question boils down to: How do I join a Kstream with another Kstream, but only with the latest event in the latter?

Comment: It's definitely a good use-case for a KTable. Could you explain what you mean with "huge disadvantage in that it will not cope with late and out-of-order data in a good fashion."?

Comment: As a Ktable constitutes the latest known value in processing time a Ktable approach would require that processing time and event time are near identical, while in many real-world scenarios (such as mine), they're not. Assume for example that event 3 in my data stream above arrives and is processed after event 3 from the meta data stream, i.e. their processing order differs from their event order. In such as case the wrong element from the meta data stream (3) would be joined in instead of the correct one (1). This would happen all the time in my use case.

Comment: You can configure event-time processing with a proper timestamp extractor to always rely on event time https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.1/streams/concepts.html#time

Comment: Still, a Ktable will only reflect the accumulative (i.e. "latest") state of all events that have been processed so far, regardless of process or event time. If an out-of-order (late) event arrives the information regarding the relevant meta data state at that particular point in event time (or process time for that matter) may be lost. So, I still argue that an enrichment approach based on Ktables will not be able to cope with out-of-order events and streams with a certain degree of time skew.

Comment: Got it. Alternatively, you can try to use just one topic / Kstream and do an aggregate instead of a join. Not ideal, but might work.