# Deduplicate intermediate results of KStream-KStream joins in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

I have the following scenario:

1. Table A and Table B joined using a FK.
2. Transactional insert/update into both A and B.
3. Debezium emits one event `a` for Table A and one event `b` for table B.
4. Kafka Streams creates KStream for Table A and B.
5. Kafka Streams application `leftJoin` KStreams A and B. (Let's assume both `a` and `b` record have same keys and fall in the join window).
6. Output records will be `[a, null], [a, b]`.

How do you discard the `[a, null]`?

An option is to perform `innerJoin` but that will still be an issue in case of `update` queries.

We tried using event timestamp for filtering (ie. keep the event with latest timestamp) but timestamp uniqueness is not guaranteed.

**ie. The end goal is to be able to identify the latest aggregate so that we can filter out intermediate results at query time (either in Athena/Presto or some RDBMS).**

Comment: Can you just `filter()` after the join? Also note, that supporting foreign-key joins is WIP atm: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-213+Support+non-key+joining+in+KTable

Comment: I can use `filter` but don't want to rely on the implementation detail that the insert will always be transactional. Think of two sequential inserts, those will be two event and for a KStream-KStream join they will output 2 records instead of just the 1 I want.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax specifically I want to figure out how to identify the latest message for each key downstream when using something like the S3 sink. I currently add a field for the `eventCreatedAt` but that's obviously same (and not guaranteed to be increasing) for events in same transaction.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495299/left-joining-a-kstream-on-another-kstream-but-only-with-latest-results?rq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the best working approach I've found is to utilize the Kafka Offsets from the output records.

The approach can be summarized as:

1. Perform all the logic that you want to do and don't worry about multiple records for the same key.
2. Write the results into an intermediate topic with a very minimal retention (1 hour etc.)
3. Read the intermediate topics using a Processor and within the Processor, enrich the message with the Kafka Offset using `context.offset()`.
4. Write the messages out to the output topic.

Now, your output topic contains multiple messages for the same key but each with a different offset.

During query time now you can select the max offsets for each key using a subquery.

An example TransformerSupplier can be seen below

```java
/**
 * @param <K> key type
 * @param <V> value type
 */
public class OutputTransformSupplier<K, V> implements TransformerSupplier<K, V, KeyValue<String, String>> {
  @Override
  public Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<String, String>> get() {
    return new OutputTransformer<>();
  }

  private class OutputTransformer<K, V> implements Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<String, String>> {
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
      this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * @param key   the key for the record
     * @param value the value for the record
     */
    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, String> transform(K key, V value) {
      if (value != null) {
        value.setKafkaOffset(context.offset());
      }
      return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, String> punctuate(long timestamp) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
      // nothing to close
    }
  }
}
```